# Select different field in mysql if a field is set to null?

Tags: mysql

I want to `select displayname as username` if username =null and if username is NOT NULL then `select username as username`
eg.

```
id username displayname
1   xyz       NULL
2   NULL      abc
```

How can I do that in one single select statement...Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

coalesce(username, dispalyname) should help you.

E.g.:

```
select coalesce(username, dispalyname) from users
where ...
```